# ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, case, ora-00905

I am getting `ORA-00905: missing keyword` error when trying to run the following query in Oracle:

```
select distinct MONTH_ID
from    DSS_MAIN.DIM_TIME a1
where   Case When TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM') < 3
Then TO_CHAR(a1.MONTH_START_DATE,'YYYYMM') Between (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')-1)||'03' And TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMM')
Else TO_CHAR(a1.MONTH_START_DATE,'YYYYMM') Between TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')||'03' And TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMM')
End;
```

The individual `Between` clauses work fine, so I am assuming there is something wrong with the `Case` syntax.

Any ideas?

Comment: The `TO_CHAR(a1.MONTH_START_DATE,'YYYYMM') Between (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')-1)||'03' And TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMM')` in the case statement makes no sense.  What are you trying to retrieve (can you explain in English)?

Comment: Additionally the expression `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')-1` does not make any sense either. Why do you subtract 1 from a *string*?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Agreed...but I guess Oracle's implicit casting rules just turns this back into a number (eg. `select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY') -1 from dual;` -> 2011

Comment: I'm trying to get a list of months YTD for a year that runs March through February. For example, if SYSDATE is in June 2012, it should return March 2012 - June 2012. If SYSDATE is February 2013, it should return March 2012 - February 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH_ID
  FROM DSS_MAIN.DIM_TIME A1
 WHERE TO_CHAR(A1.MONTH_START_DATE, 'YYYYMM') 
            BETWEEN CASE
                        WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM') < '03' THEN
                            (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')) - 1) || '03'
                        ELSE
                            TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') || '03'
                    END
                AND  TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMM')
```

Case returns a value for further use, it will not be useful in the way you used it.

Comment: @hmmftg:  only EvanMPW can do that.  ...and he should if it works for him.